# Equivalent of mod_proxy ProxyPreserveHost in IIS?

Tags: oracle, iis, oracle-apex

I have installed Oracle Apex in a server running IIS 10. Apex is accessible via localhost:8080

I'm using a reverse proxy to map my domain to apex and get rid of the port number (8080) in the url.

Now I can access Apex via mydomain.com, however when trying to connect to a workspace, I'm getting the error :

**The request cannot be processed because this resource does not support Cross Origin Sharing requests, or the request Origin is not authorized to access this resource. If ords is being reverse proxied ensure the front end server is propagating the host name, for mod_proxy ensure ProxyPreserveHost is set to On**

Does anyone know how to configure that in IIS please ?

Txhanks.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/936922/setting-up-iis-reverse-proxy-to-preserve-host-headers

Comment: Application Request Routing has an option to preserve the original host header: preserveHostHeader. This option is by default false. You can enable it with:`"C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe" set config -section:system.webServer/proxy /preserveHostHeader:"True" /commit:apphost` or by steting in web.config file:`<proxy enabled="true" preserveHostHeader="true" /></system.webServer>`

Comment: You might also read through this series, notably parts 6 and 7, which discusses setting up a reverse proxy using Nginx (even if just to learn more about how things work): https://dgielis.blogspot.com/2019/09/best-and-cheapest-oracle-apex-hosting.html